# Javadoc methods and inherited methods

Tags: java, javadoc

In javadoc, why is there a separate section for inherited methods?  For example in LinkedList, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html, there is a Method Summary section and a section for inherited methods, like "Methods inherited from interface java.util.List".  Some of the method in Method Summary are inherited from other classes so why is there this separate section?  How does javadoc decide which methods to put in the Method Summary and which in the inherited section (even when a method in Method Summary is inherited)?

Answer (score 1):

It uses the [Reflection-API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) to decide whether a method is inherited or not.

- `getMethod()` returns inherited methods
- `getDeclaredMathod()` returns all methods

for further references see also [Discovering Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html)

An example that demonstrates the usage of the API

```
public class Reflect extends ArrayList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reflect r = new Reflect();
        r.dump();
    }

    private void dump() {
        Method[] methods = this.getClass().getMethods();
        Set<String> ms = new  HashSet<String>();
        for ( Method m : methods ) {  
            ms.add( m.getName() );
        }
        Method[] declMethods = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        Set<String> ds = new  HashSet<String>();
        for ( Method m : declMethods ) {  
            ds.add( m.getName() );
        }
        for ( String name : ms ) {
            System.out.println(name + " is inherited =" +! ds.contains(name));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers it.  The thing is that some of the methods in the "Method Summary" section are actually inherited from a superclass in the ArrayList API.  So why are these not in the "is inherited from" section?  One could argue the "Method Summary" methods override the superclass version, but some of the methods in the "is inherited from" section also override superclass versions.